# reference for the slokam kalashepo na kartavyaha

Tags: reference-request

Can some one tell me reference for the following slokam

> Kālakṣēpo na kartavyaha kṣinamāyuhu kṣaṇē kṣaṇē
>
> Yamasya karuṇā nāsti kartavyam harikīrtanam

Rough meaning goes as follows :

Kalakshepo na kartavyaha.. I think Kalakshepam in this context does not refer to just time pass, it refers to discourse.. One need not join in discourse..

Kshinam ayu Kshane kshane.. Aayu (life span) is kshinam (reducing) kshane kshane (per second)..

Yamasya Karuna nasthi.. Yama does not have Mercy on us..

Kartavyam harikeertanam.. our job is to do Hari Keerthanam...

Comment: found it here - https://bhajan.sringeri.net/english/bhajan/7.html . Maybe check with sringeri piTa scholars for source

Comment: @ram thanks for the link..if you find more, please do let me know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sloka is part of the dakshina sampradaya bhajan. The tradition is to sing the following in order

1. Pundareekam and Prathivachanam.
2. Dhyana Slokam
3. Thodaya Mangalam
4. Guru Dhyanam

and so on in a particular order.

In #2, you have namavali and then avatharika slokas. The sloka you quoted is part of the avatharika slokas.

Please see here

https://srimadbhajanamrutham.blogspot.com/2011/07/iiiavatharika-slokas.html

I think the source can also be found in the subhashita ratna bhandagara but I am not sure.

https://archive.org/details/SubhashitaRatnaBhandagara/page/n15/mode/1up